# Installation Error: pecl_http

Tags: php, macos

I was trying to install peel_http extension in my mac and seriously its being a headache now. I followed this tutorial http://php-osx.liip.ch/ but when I give the command `/usr/local/php5/bin/pecl install pec_http`, it gives me error and here is my terminal stack. I really want to get started as soon as possible. Also if their is any other way working out, which is better than this, Pls do suggest me.
Here goes my stack.

```
sh-3.2# sudo /usr/local/php5/bin/pecl install pecl_http
No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/pecl_http"
install failed
sh-3.2# apachectl start 
sh-3.2# export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
sh-3.2# echo "$PATH"
/usr/local/php5/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/milind/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/
sh-3.2# /usr/local/php5-5.5.27-20150710-230047/bin/pecl install pecl_http
downloading pecl_http-2.5.3.tgz ...
Starting to download pecl_http-2.5.3.tgz (191,863 bytes)
.........................................done: 191,863 bytes
64 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20121113
Zend Module Api No:      20121212
Zend Extension Api No:   220121212 
where to find zlib [/usr] : 
where to find libcurl [/usr] : 
where to find libevent [/usr] : 
where to find libidn [/usr] : 
building in /private/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootFpNzEE/pecl_http-2.5.3
running: /private/tmp/pear/temp/pecl_http/configure --with-http-zlib-dir=/usr --with-http-libcurl-dir=/usr --with-http-libevent-dir=/usr --with-http-libidn-dir=/usr
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
checking for PHP prefix... /usr/local/php5
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/local/php5/include/php -I/usr/local/php5/include/php/main -I/usr/local/php5/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/php5/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/php5/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/php5/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/local/php5/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking if awk is broken... no
checking whether to enable extended HTTP support... yes, shared
checking for egrep... (cached) /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for off_t... yes
checking for mbstate_t... yes
checking netdb.h usability... yes
checking netdb.h presence... yes
checking for netdb.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking wchar.h usability... yes
checking wchar.h presence... yes
checking for wchar.h... yes
checking wctype.h usability... yes
checking wctype.h presence... yes
checking for wctype.h... yes
checking arpa/inet.h usability... yes
checking arpa/inet.h presence... yes
checking for arpa/inet.h... yes
checking for gethostname... yes
checking for getdomainname... yes
checking for mbrtowc... yes
checking for mbtowc... yes
checking for iswalnum... yes
checking for inet_pton... yes
checking for idna.h... not found
checking for idn2.h... not found
checking unicode/uidna.h usability... no
checking unicode/uidna.h presence... no 
checking for unicode/uidna.h... no
checking for uidna_IDNToASCII... no
checking for __uidna_IDNToASCII... no
checking for uidna_IDNToASCII in -licucore... yes
checking for zlib.h... not found
configure: error: could not find zlib.h
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/temp/pecl_http/configure --with-http-zlib-dir=/usr --with-http-libcurl-dir=/usr --with-http-libevent-dir=/usr --with-http-libidn-dir=/usr' failed
```

I Really don't know how to solve this. All kinds of help will be appreciated. Thank You so much.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem installing in a OSX. I'm not sure of your OSX version.

Update Xcode and then install “Command Line Tools (OS X) for Xcode”.

You can try to type in terminal:

```
xcode-select --install
```

If you have troubles downloading, you can download it in Apple Dev but you will need a free Apple Developer account in order to log in and download the command line tools. They have a new Downloads for Apple Developers site where you can download and install Command Line Tools (OS X Mavericks) for Xcode.

Here's the link:

https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/

After installing the command line tools,

```
sudo pecl install pecl_http
```

I restarted apache and was good to go!